# Function inside React Functional Component loses context when being passed down to child component

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, react-functional-component

I have a parent component **DrawingGrid** and a child component **ContextMenu**.
Inside the parent component **DrawingGrid**, I have a variable *existingPoints* in which I want to delete a point when I press the delete button of the **ContextMenu** of said point.
So I pass down the function *handleDeleteNode()* to my child component **ContextMenu**, where I call the fuction onClick.
But when I press the "Delete" button, the accessed *existingPoints* variable is empty, although I try to access it inside the parent component **DrawingGrid**.
The log inside the function resolves into: DELETING NODE:  []
So I suspect that the function *handleDeleteNode()* somehow loses the context or picks up an old state when it tries to access the *existingPoints* variable, but I didn't succeed in solving it.

**DrawingGrid.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import ContextMenu from './ContextMenu'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
`

const InputWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
`

const DrawingGrid = ({input}) => {

function onClickCalculate (){
    ...
    isActive = false;
}

let canvas = null;
let bounds = null;
let ctx = null;
let hasLoaded = false;

let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;
let isDrawing = false;
let isDragging = false;
let draggingPointIndex = null;
let selectedNodeIndex = null;
let existingPoints = [];
let isActive = true;
const nodeButtonRadius = 4;

const [position, setPosition] = useState([0,0]);
const [showContextMenu, setShowContextMenu] = useState(false);
const [menuPosition, setMenuPosition] = useState([]);

let img = document.getElementById("image");

function draw() {
    ...
}

const handleDeleteNode = () => {
    console.log("DELETING NODE: ", existingPoints)
    /*let copy = existingPoints
    selectedNodeIndex > -1 && existingPoints.splice(selectedNodeIndex, 1);
    console.log("EXISTING POINTS BEFORE AND AFTER DELETION: ", copy, existingPoints)
    draw();*/
}

const onHandleReset = () => {
    console.log("EXISTING POINTS: ", existingPoints)
    isActive = true;
    existingPoints = [];
    draw();
}

function onmousedown(e) {
    ...
}

function onmouseup(e) {
    ...
}

function onmousemove(e) {
    ...
}

const canvasRef = React.useRef();
const imageRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        existingPoints.forEach((point) => {
            if( Math.abs(mouseX - point[0]) <= nodeButtonRadius && Math.abs(mouseY - point[1]) <= nodeButtonRadius ){
                selectedNodeIndex = existingPoints.indexOf(point)
                console.log("SHOW CONTEXT MENU OF NODE: ", selectedNodeIndex)
                setShowContextMenu(true);
                setMenuPosition(point);
            }
        })

    });
    canvas.width = 1280;
    canvas.height = 622;
    canvas.onmousedown = onmousedown;
    canvas.onmouseup = onmouseup;
    canvas.onmousemove = onmousemove;
    
    bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    draw();
}, [])

return (
    <Wrapper>
        <h5>Drawing Grid</h5> 
        <h2>Position: {position[0]} {position[1]}</h2>         
        <canvas id="canvas" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
        <InputWrapper>
            <button onClick={() => onHandleReset()}>Zurücksetzen</button>  
            <button onClick={() => onClickCalculate()}>Fläche berechnen --></button>
        </InputWrapper> 
        <img 
            alt="tracking-objects" 
            hidden={true} id="image" 
            src="/assets/rect-test-area.jpg"
            ref={imageRef}
        >
        </img>
        {showContextMenu && 
            <ContextMenu 
                marginLeft={menuPosition[0]} 
                marginTop={menuPosition[1]} 
                onDeleteNode={() => handleDeleteNode()}
                onCloseMenu={() => setShowContextMenu(false)}
            />
        }
    </Wrapper>
)
}

export default DrawingGrid
```

**ContextMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
...
`

const MenuElementButton = styled.button`
border: none;    
flex-grow: 1;
background-color: yellow;
outline: 1px solid black;
`

const MenuText = styled.p`
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
`

const ContextMenu = ({marginLeft, marginTop, onDeleteNode, onCloseMenu}) => {
return (
    <Wrapper marginLeft={marginLeft} marginTop={marginTop}>
        <MenuElementButton>
            <MenuText>Edit</MenuText>
        </MenuElementButton>
        <MenuElementButton onClick={() => onDeleteNode()}>
            <MenuText>Delete</MenuText>
        </MenuElementButton>
        <button
            style={{boder: "none", padding: "5px"}}
            onClick={() => onCloseMenu()}
        >Schließen</button>
    </Wrapper>
)}

export default ContextMenu
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a *Ref* to save the value of *existingPoints* from a rerender.
`let existingPoints = useRef([]);`
When I wanted to change the value of *existingPoints*, I simply used *existingPoints.current* to read or change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass a state variable instead of a local variable to solve your problem. It is not possible to persist state in local variables as these are initialized every time the function is evaluated.

```
const [existingPoints, setExistingPoints] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually solved the problem by defining my existingPoints array as a ref, which then wasn't reset on every render.